# Continuity of the approximations

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space, $r>0$ and $B\subset X$ non-empty. Assume that $f:B\longrightarrow X$ is continuous, and for each $f(x)\in f(B)$ there exists a unique $y_{x}\in C$ such that $\|f(x)-y_{x}\|\leq r$, for certain (we can assume even convex and compact) $C\subset f(B)$, $C\neq f(B)$.

So, we can define the function $g:B \longrightarrow X$ by $g(x):=y_{x}$, with $y_{x}$ as above. As $y_{x}$ is unique, $g$ is well defined. My question is: Can we prove that $g$ si continuous?

Many thanks in advance for your comments and/or suggestions.

Comment: Yes, but that is the "extremal case". In a more general context, the set of the indicated $y_{x}$ is nto the whole set $f(B)$. I change the post, Thaks for your comments!

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Namely, if $C$ is convex and contains at least two points, then it contains a non-degenerated segment $I$. Then for each point $x\in f^{-1}(I)$ there are infinitely many points $y\in I\subset C$ such that $\|x-y\|\le r$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But, the continuity is about the function g(x) of the statement. By the compactness of C, you can even assume that C is finite? Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C\subset f(B)$ then the uniqueness of $y_x$ implies that $\|x-y\|>r$ for any distinct points $x,y\in C$. Since $C$ is compact, it is finite. Thus the set $f(B)$ is contained in the union of a finite family $\mathcal D$ of pairwise disjoint closed balls of radius $r$ centered at points of $C$. For each subset $C’$ of $C$, $g^{-1}(C’)=\bigcup\{ f^{-1}(D): D\in\mathcal D$ and $D$ is centered at some point of $C’\}$. Since the map $f$ is continuous and the family $\mathcal D$ is finite, the set $g^{-1}(C’)$ is closed and thus the map $g$ is continuous.

But the map $g$ is continuous even when we do not require $C\subset f(B)$. Indeed, let $x\in B$ be any point and $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence of points of $B$ converging to $x$. Since $C$ is compact, a sequence $\{g(x_n)\}$ has a cluster point $y\in C$. Then $f(x_n)$ is contained in a closed ball $B_0$ of radius $r$ centered at $y$ for infinitely many $n$. By the continuity of $f$, $f(x)\in B_0$, so $g(x)=y$. Suppose to the contrary that $\{g(x_n)\}$ does not converge to $y$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $y$ and a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that $g(x_{n_k})\in C\setminus U$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Since $C\setminus U$ is compact, a sequence $\{g(x_{n_k}):k\in\Bbb N \}$ has a cluster point $y’\in C\setminus U$. Then similarly to the above we can show that $g(x)=y’\ne y$, a contradiction.

On the other hand, if we relax the compactness of $C$ then the function $g$ can be discontinuous. For instance, let $X=\ell_2$ with the standard basis $\{e_n\}$ (for each natural $n$, $n$-th coordinate of $e_n$ is $1$, and the other coordinates are zeroes). Let $C=\{0\}\cup \{e_1+(1+1/n)e_n: n\in\Bbb N\}$, $B=\{e_1\}\cup \{e_1+e_n/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, $r=1$, and $f$ be the identity map. Then $g(e_1)=0$, $\{e_1+e_n/n\}$ converges to $e_1$, but a sequence $\{g(e_1+e_n/n)\}= \{e_1+(1+1/n)e_n\}$ is not even Cauchy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assume that "By the continuity of $f$, $x\in B_{0}$", means that "$f(x)\in B_{0}", not?

Comment: @user123043 Right, I fixed this. Thanks for the attention and sorry for the misprint.